# No search results for domain on google and other search engines

Tags: indexing, search-engine, google-search, google-crawlers

We have a domain, which is active already about 1 year. All the time there was a message "Under construction". Some months ago we have launched a new website on this domain.

And now we have a problem to get any search result on any search engine. We have double checked robots.txt and other settings - all seems to be OK. There are multiple websites with similar settings on this web server - and there are no problems with them.

We have tried to setup Google Search Console (there was no problem while approving domain ownership) and request indexing, but got an error - "Indexing request rejected". There also is an error while adding sitemap.xml in search console.

How we can resolve this problem? The domain name is pswgroup.lv

[image: Indexing request rejected]

Comment: This question has been asked and answered on Pro Webmasters: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: I voted to close this question because general SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Since this question has already been asked and answered there, you should just delete this question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days the error disappeared by itself. No problems now.